# Работа с com портом

Tags: c#, com-порт

Надо организовать чтение с com - порта. Не могу понять почему данные не приходят, т.е. событие `DataReceived` не срабатывает.

```
private void AcceptSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
            serialPort.PortName = "COM1";
            serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
            serialPort.Open();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            serialPort.Close();
     }
  }

private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 
     this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate)); 
}

private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
      StreamWriter fs=null;
      try
      {
            fs = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
            str = serialPort.ReadExisting();
            fs.WriteLine(str);
            MessageBox.Show(str);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
           fs.Close();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Оно совсем не срабатывает, или вы вычитываете только первые несколько байт? Если второе, то попробуйте читать просто в соседнем потоке, а не по событию реагировать. Способ немного топорный, но для ComPort единственно верный. Это мое имхо конечно, но оно частично следует из документации и самого способа работы. DataReceived срабатывает на появление байта, при этом нет гарантии что оно выбросится на каждый байт.

Если оно не приходит совсем, то возможно это не тот ком-порт =) На терминал с этого порта что то шлется?

Comment: Да используя утилиты я читаю с этого порта!(Порт в утилите закрываю)

Comment: Надо начать с простого получения данных. Попробуйте открыть порт и сделать ReadLine(), без потоков и событий. Если в данных нету перевода строк, то прочитайте то кол-во байт которое ждете.