# Не читаются данные с реального COM - порта

Tags: c++, c++-cli, arduino, com-порт

Стоит следующая задача:
необходимо прочесть данные с COM - порта, и при приходе каких-то определенных данных, должно произойти заранее определенное событие.
Основная проблема заключается в невозможности считать данные с реального COM - порта, к которому подключена Arduino. В Arduino зашита программа, отправляющая через каждый интервал времени символ.
Особенность проблемы заключается в том, что она не возникает при тестировании программы с использованием виртуального COM-порта.
Код, который я использовал, был взят с msdn.
Код:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#using <System.dll>


using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class PortChat
{
private:
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort^ _serialPort;

public:

    static void Main()
    {
        String^ name;
        String^ message;
        StringComparer^ stringComparer = StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        Thread^ readThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(PortChat::Read));

        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = gcnew SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort->PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort->PortName);
        _serialPort->BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(_serialPort->BaudRate);
        _serialPort->Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort->Parity);
        _serialPort->DataBits = SetPortDataBits(_serialPort->DataBits);
        _serialPort->StopBits = SetPortStopBits(_serialPort->StopBits);
        _serialPort->Handshake = SetPortHandshake(_serialPort->Handshake);

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort->ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;

        _serialPort->Open();
        _continue = true;
        readThread->Start();

        Console::Write("Name: ");
        name = Console::ReadLine();

        Console::WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

        while (_continue)
        {
            message = Console::ReadLine();

            if (stringComparer->Equals("quit", message))
            {
                _continue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _serialPort->WriteLine(
                    String::Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message) );
            }
        }

        readThread->Join();
        _serialPort->Close();
    }

    static void Read()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {
                String^ message = _serialPort->ReadLine();
                Console::WriteLine(message);

                String^ ls = (*message).Trim();
                if ((*ls).Equals("collapse")) {
                    cout << "DONE" << endl;
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ^) { }
        }

    }

    static String^ SetPortName(String^ defaultPortName)
    {
        String^ portName;

        Console::WriteLine("Available Ports:");
        for each (String^ s in SerialPort::GetPortNames())
        {
            Console::WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console::Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
        portName = Console::ReadLine();

        if (portName == "")
        {
            portName = defaultPortName;
        }
        return portName;
    }

    static Int32 SetPortBaudRate(Int32 defaultPortBaudRate)
    {
        String^ baudRate;

        Console::Write("Baud Rate(default:{0}): ", defaultPortBaudRate);
        baudRate = Console::ReadLine();

        if (baudRate == "")
        {
            baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
        }

        return Int32::Parse(baudRate);
    }

    static Parity SetPortParity(Parity defaultPortParity)
    {
        String^ parity;

        Console::WriteLine("Available Parity options:");
        for each (String^ s in Enum::GetNames(Parity::typeid))
        {
            Console::WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console::Write("Enter Parity value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortParity.ToString());
        parity = Console::ReadLine();

        if (parity == "")
        {
            parity = defaultPortParity.ToString();
        }

        return (Parity)Enum::Parse(Parity::typeid, parity);
    }

    static Int32 SetPortDataBits(Int32 defaultPortDataBits)
    {
        String^ dataBits;

        Console::Write("Enter DataBits value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortDataBits);
        dataBits = Console::ReadLine();

        if (dataBits == "")
        {
            dataBits = defaultPortDataBits.ToString();
        }

        return Int32::Parse(dataBits);
    }

    static StopBits SetPortStopBits(StopBits defaultPortStopBits)
    {
        String^ stopBits;

        Console::WriteLine("Available Stop Bits options:");
        for each (String^ s in Enum::GetNames(StopBits::typeid))
        {
            Console::WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console::Write("Enter StopBits value (None is not supported and \n" +
            "raises an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. \n (Default: {0}):", defaultPortStopBits.ToString());
        stopBits = Console::ReadLine();

        if (stopBits == "")
        {
            stopBits = defaultPortStopBits.ToString();
        }

        return (StopBits)Enum::Parse(StopBits::typeid, stopBits);
    }

    static Handshake SetPortHandshake(Handshake defaultPortHandshake)
    {
        String^ handshake;

        Console::WriteLine("Available Handshake options:");
        for each (String^ s in Enum::GetNames(Handshake::typeid))
        {
            Console::WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console::Write("Enter Handshake value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortHandshake.ToString());
        handshake = Console::ReadLine();

        if (handshake == "")
        {
            handshake = defaultPortHandshake.ToString();
        }

        return (Handshake)Enum::Parse(Handshake::typeid, handshake);
    }
};



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    PortChat::Main();
}
```

Код вшитый в Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.write("collapse");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: Правда для unix-подобных систем:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842163/how-to-read-from-serial-device-in-c

Comment: Я у вас вообще не вижу обращения к порту. Вижу обращение к консоли... а к порту? Наверно забыли. Код очень запутанный, не понятно зачем вам нужны ф-ции читающие что-то с консоли. Упростите код, тогда возможно будет видно где ошибка.

Comment: Посмотрите примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223995/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-com-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc например. Возможно у вас перепутано имя порта.